# Adjust Thread pool size when using twistd

Tags: twisted

I am going to deploy my app in the twistd way(Application,Service, etc).

I'm wondering if there is a way to adjust the thread pool size of twisted like using reactor.suggestPoolSize()

I found an API called "adjustPoolsize" in twisted.python.threadpool.ThreadPool

Can I call it directly for my purpose?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recent versions of Twisted let you access the reactor's thread pool:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
threadpool = reactor.getThreadPool()
threadpool.adjustPoolsize(3, 7)
```

However, there's no guarantee that the reactor itself won't re-adjust the size as it sees fit.  If you need to control the size of the threadpool used by your application, it may be better to create your own `ThreadPool` instance, rather than using the reactor's.

Comment: Thank you Paul~ I would like to know how to resize the threadpool when **deploy app in the twistd way**.  There is no explicit to use reactor in code.

Comment: You can always import the global reactor.

Comment: Yeah, I got your idea. Import reactor, but not .run(), Right?